# insert into Select not working for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Insert into select Statement that is not working for one column 'DataValue_Money_USD' which is money field!

Select Statement is pulling 5 rows for DataValue_Money_USD is not null and values are

```
1.04
520.00
13.52
23.92
2.08
```

still it inserts null in that column for those 5 rows in DataWorking table!

I do get 5 rows affected message twice printed in messages tab when I run it

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataWorking]
    ([TranData_ID]
    ,[Tran_ID]
    ,[DataField_ID]
    ,[DataValue_Money_USD])
SELECT
     [TranData_ID]
    ,[Tran_ID]
    ,[DataField_ID]
    ,[DataValue_Money_USD]
FROM [dbo].[TData]
WHERE Tran_ID = 1706 and DataValue_Money_USD is not null
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the data types for the two money fields.

Comment: That query is fine and will work, if what you said about your data is true. Is that your real query, copy and pasted from SSMS? Comment out the insert and run the select by itself. Are there any triggers on the `DataWorking` table?

Comment: A trigger on `DataWorking` perhaps?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek is absolutely right! If your statement prints records affected twice, you have a triger.

Comment: Yeah! it was trigger indeed! thank you for fast comments!