# Postgres insert-into-select leaves one column null, while populating others

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-insert

I have a table MAIN which contains some daily records. I copy some columns with some aggregations to some monthly aggregate tables, AGG1, AGG2, AGG3.

Recently created a new column type smallint, its basically a flag and contains only zeros and ones. This was added to all the tables, the main one and the aggregate ones.

I need the flag to be set only for 2019, the data in the table is for several years. So its a nullable field in all the tables. I updated all the rows of the MAIN with the proper flag value for year 2019.

Then I want to propagate this value back to the AGG tables.

When I run a Insert-Into-Select from the MAIN table to all of the aggregate tables, the new column remains null, while every other column is updated for AGG1. The new smallint is not copied over.

AGG2 and AGG3 are populated properly.

Since the aggregate tables are monthly, I first delete any data say for January before inserting the new records.

1. I ran this in kettle and sqlworkbench with similar result.
2. If I run only to select to see what is returned, I see all the correct values for all fields.

3.. I am able to copy all the values for AGG1 into a new temporary table I created just to check if the values are copied over. It just fails specifically for AGG1.

3. AGG1 doesn't have any trigger. It is a partitioned table, as are all others.
4. [insert into Select not working for one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251360/insert-into-select-not-working-for-one-column) is a similar problem, but there the table had triggers.

```
INSERT INTO AGG1 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... --some aggregates here
FROM MAIN
WHERE condition;
```

I don't get any error, it simply says 0 rows affected, though it actually adds all the rows (over 10k), but I read on stackoverflow this can happen with partitioned tables.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I am able to update this column later, but that is not possible as I don't have the flag info anymore.

Comment: Finally created a new table and cpied over all the values. It seems sometimes adding a new column to an old table makes it behave unexpectedly.